# my c++ vector elements getting deleted

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I'm new to c++, and working on making a 2D game.
I seem to have run into a problem with animating my sprites:

I have a class which contains a private multidimentional vector of the animation data for one sprite(sheet). The class works something like this:

```
#include <vector>

class myClass {

private:
    std::vector< std::vector<float> > BigVector;

public:
    //constructor: fills the multidimentional vector 
    //with one-dimentional vectors returned by myfunction.
    myClass() {

        //this line is called a few times within a while loop
        std::vector<float> holder = myFunction();

    }

    std::vector<float> myFunction() {

        std::vector<float> temp;
        //fill temp
        return temp;
    }

    //Other class access point for the vector
    float getFloat(int n, int m) {
        return Vector[n][m];
    }
};
```

This class itself is contained by another class, which retrieves the data using the getFloat function.

At the end of the constructor, the BigVector is filled with a number of vectors containing floats, as it should be. However, when the constructor exits and I want to retrieve the data using the getFloat function, BigVector only contains 1 element; the first element that was added.

I believe it has something to do with the holder vector going out of scope...
Any ideas?

EDIT

I've found the answer: the fault is not with this class, but with the class that uses it:
Instead of (re)declaring my private "Animator", I declared a local variable, which prevented my Animator from updating. Basicly:

```
private: Animator A //calls upon the default construstor of Animator class
```

then declaring in a function/constructor

```
Animator A(parameters); //creates a local instance of Animator called A
```

instead of

```
A = Animator(parameters); //redeclares A as a new Animator with the parameters
```

which is what I wanted. My default constructor added one vector to BigVector, causing me to think the rest of BigVector got deleted.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just a typo, but it should be

```
float getFloat(int n, int m) {
   return BigVector[n][m];
}         ^^^
```

Also, you're just filling the temporary `holder` vector and never copying the data to `BigVector`. You should do instead:

```
myClass() 
{
   std::vector<float> holder = myFunction();
   BigVector.push_back(holder); // Put the newly filled vector in the multidimensional vector.
}
```

Also you may want to use references instead of copying by value when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Banex!
The Examle code was a bit sloppy, as I gather from your pointers :P

Comment: @NyteQuist Would you please accept my reply as the answer if it helped you? Thank you :)